# Simple text block inside preference-headers

Tags: android, android-fragments, preferenceactivity

```
<preference-headers xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- What do I have to paste here? -->

    <header
        android:fragment="com.example.ASettings$GeneralPreferenceFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_info_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/pref_header_general" />
```

I want to inject here multiline text.

Comment: could you explain what do you want to do??
you want your header to have multi line title or what??

Comment: I want to add one more header with 8-10 lines of text. `header` tag only supports 2 lines.

Comment: @MohammadZarei i do not know how to inject `TextView` or similar element.

Comment: I not sure that you be able to use any other elements.
Did you try to use "\n"??

Comment: @MohammadZarei , just 2 lines with '...' and the end.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand what u said. Could you please upload an image of what you want to achieve?